# There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T'

Tags: c#, generics

I have a problem when I'm trying to create an instance of generic class where I must declare my generic type as an Interface. 
Here is code example:

```
public interface ITypeInterface
{
}

public class DataWorker<T> where T : ITypeInterface
{
    private string _someData;
    public DataWorker(string someData){
        _someData = someData;
    }
    ...
}

public class AnotherClass : MustBeInterface
{

    void MustBeInterface.CreateData<T>(string data)
    {
        // Here I should call DataWorker which has type ITypeInterface
        // but compiler gives me an error:
        // there is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'ITypeInterface'
        var dataWorker = new DataWorker<T>(data);
    }
}

public interface MustBeInterface{
    void CreateData<T>(string data);
}
```

So in class AnotherClass I must implement MustBeInterface which is part of library and I can't change it. When I try to create an instance of DataWorker inside AnotherClass.CreateData I received the error: there is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'ITypeInterface'. 
Is there any solution to achieve my goal?

Comment: `T` in `MustBeInterface.CreateData<T>` is not constrained to `ITypeInterface`.

Comment: The generic method `MustBeInterface.CreateData` does not have any clue on your constraint on `DataWorker`.

Comment: Seems like it's impossible and @CodeCaster it's not a duplicate since OP cannot add constraint to third party dll

Comment: What is the requirement in the case when `T` is not compatible with `DataWorker`? Do you want to throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this:

```
void MustBeInterface.CreateData<T>(string data)
{
    // Here I should call DataWorker which has type ITypeInterface
    // but compiler gives me an error:
    // there is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'ITypeInterface'
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(ITypeInterface))
        var dataWorker = new DataWorker<ITypeInterface>(data);
    else throw new IllegalOperationException(...);
}
```